# The file upload working in IIS express but not working on local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

[image]
I have dropZone in my project (ASP.Net MVC) the Upload file work correctly in IIS express but it does not working when I use local IIS

Comment: You have a credential issue.  Users connecting to a server only have Guest Privileges.  404 indicates an error due to server refusing the connection.  The best way of solving issues like this is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working application against non working application.

Comment: I am not sure, that this is a credential issue. Are you sure, the folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Upload\Upload` exists on the server? Btw.: If this should be a real application, you should think about authorization. It is not a good idea, that an anonymous user could upload files to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has been fixed, the error was caused, local IIS cannot read action form path correctly for uploading files method, just I've added the ~ sign after action path, but IIS Express does not need that, for this reason, it was difficult to detect the error
Thank you ALL

Answer (score 1):

i think its the folder mapping issue
you didnot map the website project correctly